# Autocomplete PHP JQuery Oracle

Tags: php, jquery, oracle, autocomplete

I'm trying to get Autocomplete to work with an Oracle DB.

I found code for testing and tried to get it to work with Oracle but it doesn't work and I don't know if the problem is in the search-form which is untouched or in the `backend-search.php` (original code is still in the code with comments #)

If I type in the textbox nothing happens.

The database connection is tested on another form where I get the data into a table.

If somebody can give me a hint I would be grateful.

search-form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Formatting search box */
    .search-box{
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"]{
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .result{
        position: absolute;        
        z-index: 999;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Formatting result items */
    .result p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .result p:hover{
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });       
    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Stationsname..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

backend-search.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

#$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");
    $db = '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = xxxxxx)(Port = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxx) ))';
    $dbuser = 'xxxxx';
    $pass = 'xxxxx';
    $conn = oci_connect($dbuser, $pass, $db);

if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    #$sql = 'SELECT Standortname FROM DATABASE WHERE Standortname LIKE :s';
    #if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
    if($stmt = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT Standortname FROM Database WHERE Standortname LIKE :s")){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        #mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
        oci_bind_by_name( $stmt , ':s' , $param_term, -1 ); #$ph_name
        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        #if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        if(oci_execute($stmt)){
            #$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $result = oci_result($stmt);
            // Check number of rows in the result set
            #if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            if(oci_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                #while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)){
                    echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . "</p>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute"; #$sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    #mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
// close connection
#mysqli_close($conn);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['term']) and (strlen($_REQUEST['term']) >= 3)){
    if($stmt = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT LOCATIONNAME from DATABASE where LOCATIONNAME like  :s  and AKTIV = 'Y'")){
    $param_term = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';    
    oci_bind_by_name( $stmt , ":s" , $param_term, -1);                                                                  
        if(oci_execute($stmt)){                                                                                         
                while(($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {                                                         
                    echo "<p>" . $row['LOCATIONNAME'] . "</p>"; # "
                }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute" . $param_term; 
        }
    }
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
```

......

This worked for me.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Please, please, *please* look at the [error log file](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) whilst developing. You have a syntax error that prevents the script from running. In this case just having `error_reporting(E_ALL);` isn't going to help you:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...

It's caused by not having a closing `}` for `if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {`.  Fix it by adding a `}` at the end of the file.

Now you'll see two warnings:

1. > Warning: oci_result() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ...

   Caused by not providing the required second parameter in `$result = oci_result($stmt);`.
2. > Warning: oci_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

   Caused by incorrectly handling the return value in `if(oci_num_rows($result) > 0){`

It looks like you've just naively replaced `mysql` functions with `oci` functions without any regard for differences in behaviour.

```
...
if (oci_execute($stmt)) {
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
        // MUST use uppercase column names.
        echo "<p>" . $row["STANDORTNAME"] . "</p>";
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Hy Tim, thank you for your input. I am really not familiar with this stuff but with your help i was able to get it working. Thank you very mutch